# cmake-gui, What is ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR error?

Tags: windows, cmake, zlib, obs

I want built OBS with cmake-gui. but "confirgure" is print error.

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Libx264 (missing: X264_LIB X264_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindLibx264.cmake:62 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  plugins/obs-x264/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/LHS/Documents/obs/obs-studio/libobs
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/LHS/Documents/obs/obs-studio/libobs
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/LHS/Documents/obs/obs-studio/libobs
```

How do i do?

Comment: The first error message you got is "Could NOT find Libx264", so you need to concentrate on resolving this error first: other errors could be a result of this first error. But if you just curious, `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` usually denotes include directory for `zlib` library; it seems that CMake cannot detect this directory on your system.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, I added libx264 and clear "Could NOT find Libx264" error. but,
ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR error is still.